# Show that $X + Y$ and $|X − Y |$ are uncorrelated

Tags: probability, expected-value, binomial-distribution, covariance

Be $X$ and $Y$ Independent Bernoulli-distributed random variables with parameter $p= \frac{1}{2}$.
Show that $X + Y$ and $|X − Y |$ are  uncorrelated.

So I have to show $cov(X + Y,|X − Y |)= 0$

$cov(X + Y,|X − Y |)= \mathbb{E}[(X+Y)|X-Y|]-\mathbb{E}[X+Y] \mathbb{E}[|X-Y|] = 0$

My problem here is to calculate the values of $\mathbb{E}[(X+Y)|X-Y|]$ , $\mathbb{E}[X+Y]$ and $\mathbb{E}[|X-Y|]$.

Could you help me to solve this?

Unfortunately there are no solutions in my exercise book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can simply do the calculations explicitly. The value $(X,Y)$ is equally likely to be any of $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1).$  Then

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[ X |X-Y| ] &= \frac{1}{4} ( 0 + 0 + 1 + 0) = \frac{1}{4}\\
\mathbb{E}[|X-Y|] &= \frac{1}{4} ( 0 + 1 + 1 + 0) = \frac{1}{2}\\
\mathbb{E}[X] &= \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{align*}
 $$

So then $\text{Cov}(X, |X-Y|) = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = 0.$ Symmetrically, $\text{Cov}(Y, |X-Y|) = 0$ as well, and by linearity we have $\text{Cov}(X+Y, |X-Y|) = 0.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: One has $(X+Y)(X-Y) = X^2-Y^2$ and for a Bernouilli variable, $X^2=X$.

Comment: Hello, but its $(X+Y)(|X-Y|)$ not $(X+Y)(X-Y)$, doesn't it make a difference ? If not than i would say u mean $\mathbb{E}[(X+Y)|X-Y|] = \mathbb{E}[X-Y]$ ?

Comment: Here $X+Y\ge 0$, so $(X+Y)|X-Y| = |(X+Y)(X-Y)|$. Don't remove absolute values just because it suits you.